# Rails select - unwanted automatic typecast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, type-conversion

DBMS is PostgreSQL.

In controller:

```
@data = current_user.myitems.all(:select => 'record_date, count(record_date) as value', :group => 'record_date')
```

In a view:

```
<% @data.each do |item| -%>
   <%= item.record_date.utc.strftime('%Y%m%d') %>
<% end -%>
```

Everything is working fine.

But if I change date field name:

```
@data = current_user.myitems.all(:select => 'record_date as recdate, count(record_date) as value', :group => 'record_date')

<% @data.each do |item| -%>
   <%= item.recdate.utc.strftime('%Y%m%d') %>
<% end -%>
```

I get the error message:

```
undefined method `utc' for "2012-02-09 17:03:47":String
```

WTF??!! I did not order to cast the type to string!!!

You may suggest not to make an alias in SQL string or to define aliases in model, but I do not want to change models to make aliases for columns, as I need aliases only once and for display purposes only. Controller's method has "**case**" statement where **multiple select statements** are present, **each with its own column names**. I need to make aliases to have solid view, without "if" statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the types of a postgres query via
[`ftype`](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Result.html#method-i-ftype).
ActiveRecord uses this information in the postgres adapter (method
`#result_as_array`) to check wherever columns need escaping then
throws away this information.

My guess on the further data flow would be that it takes the column
name and uses the data gained via reflection from the database to
determine the type. Since the basic type is `String`, you get that.
So, use the column types rails expects or hack the postgres adapter
and ActiveRecord to ask the column types via `ftype`.

tl;dr: Alias the stuff on the Ruby side (in the model somewhere) AR
doesn't like what you're doing.

Comment: It would be a heap of thrash if I create aliases for each temporary data I need. Is there some way to rename column in a result set AFTER select is done? Or to pass aliases to SELECT as parameters? I'll try ftype.

Comment: I didn't get why you need those aliases? And some metaprogramming should keep the footprint small.

Comment: Let's imagine that you should have multiple selects in one controller's method. Which of them will be executed depends on input parameter. The output columns names should be the same to keep single view, without CASE statements.